# Blackjack python game

Tags: python

I have to create a blackjack game in python in which the user inputs the number of decks that are being used and the amount of money the user wants to bet. The rules are: o    The player places his bet (should be read from the keyboard).
o   The dealer and player are dealt two cards (one card of the dealer should be hidden).
o   If the player has 21 he wins his bet; else if the dealer has 21 then the dealer wins and the player loses his bet.
o   The player can only select to draw a new card (hit) or pass. Repeat until the player passes or busts. If the player goes above 21 then he busts.
o   Then the dealer draws cards (automatically) until he either busts or reaches 17 or higher.
o   Values of cards: A= 1 or 11 (the highest that does not bust you) and J=Q=K=10
o   Note: in blackjack there are more actions: insurance, double, split; those are not required to be implemented as they would make the code you have to produce much, much longer and harder

I will show you my code below when I tried to run it, it said that the name "total" is not defined on the function game, but earlier on I have already defined it. I don't know how can i fix it.

```
import random

N=int(input("Please enter number of decks of cards used: "))

deck= [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]*N

wins=0
losses=0
chip_pool = 100
bet = 1

def deal(deck):
    hand = []
    for i in range(2):
        random.shuffle(deck)
        card=deck.pop()
        if card == 11:
            card = "J"
        if card == 12:
            card = "Q"
        if card == 13:
            card = "K"
        if card == 14:
            card = "A"
        hand.append(card)
    return hand

def play_again():
    again = input("Do you want to play again? (Y/N) : ").lower()
    if again == "y":
        dealer_hand = []
        player_hand = []
        deck = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]*N
        game()
    else:
        print("Thank you for playing.")
        exit()

def total_hand():
    total = 0
    for card in hand:
        if card == "J" or card == "Q" or card == "K":
            total = total + 10
        elif card == "A":
            if total >=11:
                total = total + 1
            else:
                total = total + 11
        else:
            total = total + card 
    return total

def hit(hand):
    card = deck.pop()
    if card == 11:
        card = "J"
    if card == 12:
        card = "Q"
    if card == 13:
        card = "K"
    if card == 14:
        card = "A"
    hand.append(card)
    return hand

def print_results(dealer_hand, player_hand):
    clear()
    
    print("\n  WELCOME TO BLACKJACK!\n")
    print("The dealer has a " + str(dealer_hand) + "for a total of" + str(total(dealer_hand)))
    print("You have a" + str(player_hand) + "for a total of" + str(total(player_hand)))

def blackjack(dealer_hand, player_hand):
    global wins
    global losses
    if total(player_hand) == 21:
        print_results(player_hand,dealer_hand)
        print("Congratulations! You got a blackjack.\n")
        wins = wins + 1
        play_again()
    elif total(dealer_hand) == 21:
        print_results(dealer_hand,player_hand)
        print("Sorry you lose. The dealer got a blackjack.\n")
        chip_pool -= bet
        loses = loses + 1
        play_again()

def score(dealer_hand,player_hand):
    if total(player_hand) == 21:
        print_results(dealer_hand, player_hand)
        print("Congratulations! You got a blackjack1\n")
    elif total(dealer_hand) == 21:
        print_results(dealer_hand, player_hand)
        print("Sorry you lose. The dealer go a blackjack\n")
    elif total(player_hand) > 21:
        print_results(dealer_hand, player_hand)
        print("Sorry, you busted. You lose.\n")
    elif total(dealer_hand) > 21:
        print_results(dealer_hand, player_hand)
        print("Dealer busts. You win!\n")
        chip_pool += bet
    elif total(player_hand) < total(dealer_hand):
        print_results(dealer_hand, player_hand)
        print("Sorry, the score is not higher than the dealer. You lose.\n")
        chip_pool -= bet 
    elif total(player_hand) > total(dealer_hand):
        print_results(dealer_hand, player_hand)
        print("Congratulations. Your score is higher than the dealer. You win.\n")
        chip_pool += bet
    elif total(player_hand)  == total(dealer_hand):
        print_results(playe_hand, dealer_hand)
        print("There is a tie. In a tie dealer always wins!\n")
        chip_pool -= bet


def make_bet():
    
    global bet
    bet = 0
    print("What amount of chips would you like to bet? ")
    while bet == 0:
        bet_comp = input()
        bet_comp = int(bet_comp)
        
        if bet_comp >= 1 and bet_comp <= chip_pool:
            bet = bet_comp
        else:
            print("Invalid bet, you only have" + str(chip_pool) + "remaining")

def game():
    choice = 0
    print("Welcome to Blackjack!\n")
    dealer_hand = deal(deck)
    player_hand = deal(deck)
    print("The dealer is showing a " +str(dealer_hand[0]))
    make_bet()
    print("You have a " + str(player_hand))
    blackjack(dealer_hand, player_hand)
    quit = False
    while not quit:
        choice = input("Do you want to [H]it, [S]tand, or [Q]uit: ").lower()
        if choice == 'h':
            hit(player_hand)
            print(player_hand)
            if total(player_hand) > 21:
                print("You busted")
                chip_pool -= bet
                play_again()
            elif choice == "s":
                while total(dealer_hand) < 17:
                    hit(dealer_hand)
                    print(dealer_hand)
                if total(dealer_hand) > 21:
                    print("Dealer busts. You win!")
                    chip_pool += bet
                    play_again()
                score(dealer_hand, playe_hand)
                play_again()
            elif choice == "q" :
                print("Thank you for playing. Hope you enjoyed!")
                quit = True 
                exit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
   game()
```

Comment: You are calling the function `total` inside other functions `game` and `blackjack` but `total` isn't defined inside `game` or `blackjack`. May be you can define all the functions as methods inside a class, and make sure that the function/method `total` also accepts an argument if required.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\USER\nick.py", line 164, in <module>
    game()
  File "c:\Users\USER\nick.py", line 137, in game    
    blackjack(dealer_hand, player_hand)
  File "c:\Users\USER\nick.py", line 75, in blackjack
    if total(player_hand) == 21:
NameError: name 'total' is not defined\

Comment: Nowhere in your code do you define a function called `total`. What do you expect `total(player_hand)` to be? You do define a function called `total_hand` (but one which takes no inputs). Is that what you are trying to call?

Comment: Your win/loss/push rules and payoffs are unlike any casino I'm familiar with.

Comment: @ΝικόλαςΟρφανίδης did my answer managed to solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

You have not defined the function `total` that you call. Try adding this to your code

```
def total(array):
    total = 0
    for card in array:
        if card == "J" or card == "Q" or card == "K":
            total = total + 10
        elif card == "A":
            if total >=11:
                total = total + 1
            else:
                total = total + 11
        else:
            total = total + card 
    return total
```

However I see some more issues in your code that will need fixing later on! Stand or Quit do nothing currently, and on busting there is an exception thrown since `chip_pool` never had a value assigned to it

EDIT 1:
You defined a function

```
def total_hand():
    total = 0
    for card in hand:
        if card == "J" or card == "Q" or card == "K":
            total = total + 10
        elif card == "A":
            if total >=11:
                total = total + 1
            else:
                total = total + 11
        else:
            total = total + card 
    return total
```

Similar to what I suggested. Maybe it was just a typo but you need to do the following

1. Rename the function from `total_hand` to `total` OR call `total_hand`
2. Change the definition from `total_hand()` to `total_hand(hand)`